# Conditionally limit results of for loop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to display the last 10 posts in a jekyll blog assuming that their `show` attribute is `true`.

e.g. the YAML front matter might look like this

```
---
title: "SO question"
categories: question
show: false
---
```

In my `index.html` file I currently have the following

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %} 
  {% if post.show %}
    <!-- display post -->
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but if one post of the last 10 has a `show` attribute of `false`, then only 9 posts would appear on the page.

Jinja2 suppports the `for-if` syntax as seen here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for. This would solve my problem, but unfortunately is not supported with liquid.

Using liquid how can I condition on a post attribute and also make sure that 10 posts are always displayed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to first make an array with posts that have the `show` variable set to `true`.

```
{% assign publishedPosts = site.posts | where: 'show', 'true' %}
```

You can then make a

```
{% for p in publishedPosts limit:10 %}
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that with liquid, nice! +1

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out on @matrixanonaly answer, it works well with a small tweek if the "where" filter can't be used. I can't comment yet but I thought I would just fix it so it works as it helped me.

```
 {% assign count = 0 %}
   {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %} 
     {% if post.show %}
         {% if count < 10 %} 
         <!-- display post -->
         {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}
         {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I needed this as I was using contains in tags. For some reason increment was just not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using `assign` to a counter variable** of posts with the `show` value set to `true`. Here's one of a few simple ways to do it.

```
{% assign count = 0 %}
   {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %} 
     {% if post.show %}
         {% if count < 10 %} 
         <!-- display post -->
         {% increment count %}
         {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That *should* work, however I don't have a Jekyll install right now to check, alternatively if increment does not work use `{% assign count = count + 1 %}`.

The [Shopify Liquid syntax manual is helpful](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/operators).

**Alternatively,** *I have a feeling* that you just want to set if a post should be published or not, in which case you **can use the built-in** `published` variable. Just do `published : true` or `published : false` in the frontmatter. Read more about pre-defined variables [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/#predefined-global-variables).